# Xcode debugger warning: Couldn't find minimal bounds for "_sigtramp" - backtraces may be unreliable

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, backtrace

What does this means? Seems to appear in the console occasionally when I run with breakpoints on in the debugger.

```
warning: Couldn't find minimal bounds for "_sigtramp" - backtraces may be unreliable
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this "error" came about because I was building in "release" and not "debug". Doh!